# how to count how many squares with different sizes in a grid with size n*m?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, discrete-mathematics

is there a formula to count each distinct square or rectangle within a rectangle for e.g if we have rectangle of size 105119*753919 , and we want to know how many 54705*91121 in it or how many 2*2 in it , is there a general formula that we can use to get the count ?

Answer (score 1):

In an n*m grid, how many i*j rectangles?

Answer: as many as places you can put the upper left corner. That is:

```
(n-i+1)*(m-j+1)
```